# How to send money from customer to merchant in Lemonway?

Tags: php

How to send money from customer Wallet to merchant Wallet,
knowing that the merchant Wallet doesn't have an ID.

i use this library : https://github.com/lemonwaysas/php-client-directkit-xml.

```
    $api = Config::getLemonWayApi();
    $data = array('debitWallet' => $customerWallet,
        'amount' => number_format(doubleval($amount),2,'.',''),
        'amountComm' => number_format(doubleval($commission),2,'.',''),
        'message' => 'Comment');
    var_dump($data);
    return $api->SendPayment($data);
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The merchant wallet does have Id. In most case, the ID is "SC", it is displayed in the BackOffice